# Moodle Double Enrolling Students Using Cohorts

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

Are students enrolled a second time for a course if they are in a second COHORT?  Or, is Moodle intelligent enough to SKIP them when the second COHORT is enrolled?

Answer (score 0):

A student can be enrolled multiple times on the same course using different enrollment methods. But will only appear once in the list of students.

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Enrolments

Students are linked to the enrollment method rather than the course.

So if a course has 2 cohort enrollment methods and the student is in both cohorts, then they will have 2 enrollment records.

eg: The `mdl_enrol` table is the enrolment method

```
SELECT *
FROM mdl_user_enrolments ue
JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = e.courseid
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = ue.userid
LIMIT 10
```